# Excel workbook function to remove existing charts in cell and replace with new chart

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build an excel function which can be used to generate a chart directly in the cell that the function is written in.  I have everything working except for one annoyance in that; when I try to copy the function from one cell to another, the chart comes with it and the pasted cell then generates its own chart on top of the copied chart.  So each time I copy a the function to new cells I have extra (erroneous) charts hanging around potentially causing confusion.  Is there any way to audit only the cell that the function is in and have it delete any existing charts before generating its own chart?

```
Function InCellTimelineChart(TitleRange As Range, DataRange As Range) As String
On Error GoTo Fail
Dim chtNewChart As ChartObject
Dim TargetCell As Range
Dim SeriesCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim TitleText As String

'Preliminary data input processing
If TitleRange.Cells.Count <> DataRange.Cells.Count Then
    InCellTimelineChart = "Mismatch in data and title counts."
    Exit Function
End If

If TitleRange.Rows.Count > 1 And TitleRange.Columns.Count > 1 Then
    InCellTimelineChart = "Titles can be selected within a single row or column only."
    Exit Function
End If

If DataRange.Rows.Count > 1 And DataRange.Columns.Count > 1 Then
    InCellTimelineChart = "Data can be selected within a single row or column only."
    Exit Function
End If

If TitleRange.Rows.Count = 1 Then
    SeriesCount = TitleRange.Columns.Count
Else
    SeriesCount = TitleRange.Rows.Count
End If


'Main Function
Set TargetCell = Application.Caller

On Error Resume Next
Set chtNewChart = TargetCell.Parent.ChartObjects(TargetCell.Address)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo Fail
Else
    chtNewChart.Delete
    On Error GoTo Fail
End If

Set chtNewChart = TargetCell.Parent.ChartObjects.Add(TargetCell.Left + 2, TargetCell.Top + 2, TargetCell.Width - 4, TargetCell.Height - 4)
chtNewChart.Name = TargetCell.Address

chtNewChart.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
chtNewChart.Chart.ClearToMatchStyle
chtNewChart.Chart.ChartStyle = 343

For i = 1 To SeriesCount
TitleText = "="""
TitleText = TitleText & Replace(TitleRange.Item(i), """", "")
TitleText = TitleText & """"

   If IsDate(DataRange.Item(i)) Then
    chtNewChart.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    chtNewChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Name = TitleText
    chtNewChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(i).XValues = "=" & TargetCell.Parent.Name & "!" & DataRange.Item(i).Address
    chtNewChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Values = "={0}"

    chtNewChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(i).ApplyDataLabels
    chtNewChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(i).DataLabels.ShowSeriesName = True
    chtNewChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(i).DataLabels.ShowValue = False
    chtNewChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(i).DataLabels.ShowCategoryName = True
    chtNewChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(i).DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
    chtNewChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(i).DataLabels.Orientation = xlUpward
    chtNewChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(i).DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.Orientation = msoTextOrientationUpward
    chtNewChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(i).DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.WordWrap = msoFalse
    chtNewChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(i).DataLabels.ShowValue = False

    With chtNewChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Format.Shadow
        .Type = msoShadow21
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .Style = msoShadowStyleOuterShadow
        .Blur = 4.5
        .OffsetX = 9.1848509936E-17
        .OffsetY = 1.5
        .RotateWithShape = msoFalse
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0.3700000048
        .Size = 100
    End With
    chtNewChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Format.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    End If
Next i

chtNewChart.Chart.Axes(xlValue).Delete
chtNewChart.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Delete
chtNewChart.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorGridlines.Delete
chtNewChart.Chart.Legend.Delete
chtNewChart.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelPosition = xlNone


With chtNewChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(5).DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 0, 0)
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With

Exit Function
Fail:
    Debug.Print "Error in InCellTimelineChart: " & vbCrLf & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    InCellTimelineChart = Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    chtNewChart.Delete
End Function
```

Comment: `Application.Caller` or `Application.ThisCell`  If either of those don't fix it then posting your code would be the next step.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have been using Application.Caller, but I don't see a method that would affect shapes in the cell.  the Shapes object has a TopLeftCell property, but I don't want to iterate over all shapes for every instance of the function being used.

Comment: "posting your code would be the next step" - please edit your question to add your function

Comment: @TimWilliams I wasn't able to get to the code for my previous reply, but now I've edited the post.  Though realistically, the concept I'm trying to get an answer for should be answerable without code if someone with sufficient knowledge of the Excel object model were to read the question.

Comment: To tell the truth I was so sure this couldn't work because of the restrictions on what a UDF in a cell can do that I really wanted to see how you got around the restriction.  In the end it seems like it "just works" which was very surprising.   So TIL something else about Excel...

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach which might meet you needs (stripped down your function to bare essentials)

```
Function InCellTimelineChart(TitleRange As Range, DataRange As Range) As String

    Dim chtNewChart As ChartObject
    Dim TargetCell As Range

    Set TargetCell = Application.Caller

    RemoveWrongChart TargetCell 'remove any chart which doesn't belong here

    On Error Resume Next
    Set chtNewChart = TargetCell.Parent.ChartObjects(TargetCell.Address)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If chtNewChart Is Nothing Then

        Set chtNewChart = TargetCell.Parent.ChartObjects.Add(TargetCell.Left + 2, TargetCell.Top + 2, _
                                      TargetCell.Width - 4, TargetCell.Height - 4)
        chtNewChart.Name = TargetCell.Address

    End If

End Function


Sub RemoveWrongChart(rng As Range)
    Dim co, i As Long
    For i = rng.Parent.ChartObjects.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set co = rng.Parent.ChartObjects(i)
        If co.TopLeftCell.Address = rng.Address And _
           co.Name <> rng.Address Then
            Debug.Print "Deleting " & co.Name & " from " & co.TopLeftCell.Address
            co.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Not ideal, because it means for every calculation you need to loop through the charts and check them, but that the downside of doing this via a UDF.